# How to merge current branch into master locally, with conflicts, ignoring changes in master?

Tags: git, gitlab

Hi I was trying to merge my current branch into master, but it said I have merge conflicts.

I tried so many answers but none of them have been able to solve my problem. The steps given by gitlab also don't seem to work.

I tried rebasing, checking out and what not. I have ended up with detached heads, and loads of things I don't really understand. What I want to know is, how to merge by current branch, named `test` into master. I don't care what is there in master. I just want to merge exactly what's there in my current branch into master. Can anyone help me?

What steps should I follow after I do

`git clone test link`

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't care what is there in master. I just want to merge exactly what's there in my current branch"? `merge` implies you want to combine changes in both your branch and master, and git is telling you there's a conflict. (e.g. a line is deleted in one branch, but that same line is changed in another branch.) Git doesn't know which one of two changes should happen.

Comment: @Kache So is it possible that I don't merge rather overwrite `test` into `master`?

Comment: Of course. `master` and `test` are both just branches "pointing" to particular state of code. There are many ways to get `master` pointing to a state of code identical to what's in `test` that leave behind different git histories behind for posterity. It just depends what kind of history you'd like to leave behind. I suggested a straightforward answer below that loses history, but there are also alternatives that retain what master used to be and perhaps even what was done to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* don't care what's in `master` (e.g. other work in `master` you or other developers have done will be "lost", and history will be changed), then:

```sh
git checkout master
git reset --hard your-branch-name
```

#### What this does

```
Before:

* B1 <- [your-branch-name]
| * C2 <- [master]
|/
* C1

After:

* B1 <- [your-branch-name][master]
| * C2 ("lost")
|/
* C1
```

**Changes in C2 will be "lost"** -- it will still exist in temporary backup for a while, but has no named branch pointing to it anymore (and will be garbage collected at some point)

**History will be changed** -- in the "After" state, it'll seem like `master` *never* had changes in C2 to begin with.

Comment: Then do I just push?

Comment: You can then push to make the remote repo into the same state as well. Since you'd be changing "history" the `master` branch, you'll have to force push.

Comment: @TabachiHarada has this been useful? Can I get a question upvote if it has?

Answer (score 0):

Please first check git status to see which files you have changed.

The use git merge to see the files which could be overwritten.

then remove them using

> rm filename

and then

> git merge.

Answer (score 0):

**With git merge**

1. Merge `master` into your `test` branch first

```
    git checkout test
    git merge master
    // fix the conflict code
    git commit -am "merge with master"
```

2. Then merge `test` into `master`

```
   git checkout master
   git merge test
```

---

**With git rebase**

1. Rebase `master` on `test`

```
    git checkout test
    git rebase master
    // fix the conflict code
    git commit -am "merge with master"
```

2. Merge `test` into `master`

```
    git checkout master
    git merge test
```